# Anyone know of a cool jquery evolving picture?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, user-interface

slightly strange request, but does anybody know of any cool jquery plugin that changes the design or shape of its picture, based on a number (i.e. like reputation points)?

Similar to the StackOverflow user icons, they seem to change and morph every now and then (possibly based on reputation), I was wondering if someone knew of a similar way to do that.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: You're referring to the [gravatar](http://gravatar.com) image, which is actually a visual representation of a hashed email. This isn't anything StackOverflow is doing - it's merely a service.

Comment: thanks, do you know if how/why it evolves over time? Is it based on rep?

Comment: It's completely unrelated to reputation. It will only change if your email address is changed, or if you have explicitly changed it via gravatar.com.

Comment: you sure?! could be my short term memory is that bad hahaha. I'm pretty sure mine has been changing over time, and I haven't changed my email.....anyway, thanks to you I found gravatar's api! if you want to answer, i'll choose you as correct :]

http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any jQuery plugins, however it's not beyond reasonable to suggest that you could create something to that effect which would convert either a string, or a hash into an image (perhaps even within a canvas element), though it's probably best to keep that away from the client machine and perform such actions on the server.

Some time back Stack Overflow launched a custom gravatar-ish alternative to "unicornify" everybody's avatars. You can learn more about that particular setup at http://unicornify.appspot.com/use-it, and the history of it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns. This was the work of [@balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha).

Gravatar keeps their algorithm under lock and key, understandably. [Avatarco](http://code.google.com/p/avatarco/) is an open-source PHP alternative that seeks to provide functionality similar to that of Gravatar. I would encourage you to peruse their source to for a better understanding of how you might accomplish something similar.

Comment: thanks! I think if I could incorporate a user's reputation-esque rating  into a cool changing icon, like gravatar's geometric shapes, it'll be pretty coooo....thanks for your help